# Data not Rendering in HTML but in log it shows

Tags: reactjs

Rendering not working in td tag, outside td the data is showing but not getting rendering HTML.
`td` not working.
Data is printing if do `console.log` but not getting render in HTML

```js
    SetArrayTime((prev_array_time) => {
      let newArray = [...prev_array_time];
      newArray.push(intervals);
      return newArray;
    });
    };
    
    
    return (
        <table className="table table-bordered">
            <thead className="thead text-center">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">From</th>
                    <th scope="col">To</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {array_time &&
                    array_time.map((d, i) => {
                        console.log("123-d", d);
    
                        return (
                            <tr key={i}>
                                <td>
                                    {d.from}-{d.to}
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
```

Comment: @harikpatel Can you share your data model? What if from and to? date or string or number? Also which td is not working? first one or the second one?

Comment: @YasinTazeoglu this is for time slot. both td is not getting render. result is like this from 8:00 am to 8:30 am and so on but in console log result array is showing but not rending

Comment: Can you add this code and share the result?
`return <pre>{JSON.stringify({array_time}, null, 2)}</pre> `

You should see a JSON output.

Comment: @YasinTazeoglu  Please you can check full code here  https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-khorana-l2hp1w?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @YasinTazeoglu but i want to show that data and send it to database in from of array

Answer (score -2):

map return array of react elemnt,react by default map of the array and render. it does not need return
Try this

```
{array_time?.map((d, i) => (
<tr key={i}>
  <td>
    {d.from}-{d.to}
  </td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
))}
```

Comment: This will yield the same result, just a different syntax.

Comment: i recreated it there is no issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-dawn-hm28n3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ok, and here is the original version without any issues: https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-river-3k5hh3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Making the `return` implicit is definitely unrelated.

Comment: not working @Bisaromer

Comment: @Bisaromer  https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-khorana-l2hp1w?file=/src/App.js  i have updated my code i want to render that but not getting result.

Comment: @tomleb  https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-khorana-l2hp1w?file=/src/App.js  i have updated my code i want to render that but not getting result.